# Efficient and stable computation of inverse CDF

Tags: probability-distributions, numerical-methods

What is the most efficient and numerically stable algorithm for computing the inverse CDF $F^{-1}(y)$ of a probability function, assuming that both the PDF $f(x)$ and the CDF $F(x)$ are known analytically but the inverse CDF is not?

Clearly, this is the same as finding the root of the nonlinear function $G(x) \equiv F(x) - y$, with $x \in \mathbb{R}$ for a given $y \in (0, 1)$. We know/assume that $G(x)$ is:

- monotonically non-decreasing (being $F(x)$ a CDF);
- differentiable at least $k \ge 1$ times (its first derivative is $G^\prime(x) = f(x)$);
- continuous (we assume that $f(x)$ is not a delta function).
- I am particularly interested in the case in which the shape of the PDF is a generic mixture of Gaussian distributions multiplied by a polynomial of arbitrary degree (in this case, the CDF can be computed analytically).

There are several standard methods for root-finding of generic nonlinear functions (see for example Chapter 9 of [Numerical Recipes](http://www.fing.edu.uy/if/cursos/fiscomp/extras/numrec/book/f9.pdf)). The method I would use is  [Brent's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brent%27s_method), with a couple of steps of [Newton-Raphson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) in the end to refine the root, but I wonder if there are better ways given the assumptions above.

Comment: IMO Newton steps to refine Brent make no sense (and may not refine at all) because Brent convergence is guaranteed and superlinear for well-behaved functions.

Comment: It is mentioned in Numerical Recipes as a good thing to do -- I'll keep in mind that it might not be a good idea after all! (It is easy to check if you *worsen* the solution.)

Comment: I posted the same question on Computational Science exchange because it was pointed out that it is probably more appropriate there. I will delete this question from here to avoid duplicates if necessary (I don't have the power to move questions).

Comment: Since the derivative is known, it may be more advantageous to use methods which rely on derivatives such as Newton's method rather than interpolations such as Brent's method, especially if the derivative is known to be "nice" beforehand and can be easily computed.